# Android: How can I toggle music?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I my application I have a background music that plays when the program starts. In menu I want to add option that user have ability to stop or start the music.

How can I know that the music is playing or stop?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you're playing it using MediaPlayer?
If so:

> ```
> MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
> mp.setDataSource(PATH_TO_FILE);
> mp.prepare();
> mp.start();
> ```
>
> stop() and pause() work the same as
>   discussed above.
>
> ...
>
> To pause playback, call pause(). Resume playback from where you paused with start().

Cut from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html).

Checking if music is playing:

```
mp.isPlaying();
```